# JS loop producing no result

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, innerhtml

Trying to create an array with a loop and then sum all the contents of the array and put the result as the contents of a `DIV` but when I run the fiddle I get no result and jshint says everything is well formed.

```
var begin = 500000;
var stop = 999999;
var arrInt = [];

// Create an array worth summing
var CreateArray = function (begin,stop) {
    while(begin < stop +1){ 
        arrInt.push(begin++);
    }
};

// Sum all ints in an array
var IntSum = function (ManyInts) {
    var i = arr.length; while (i--) { 
        return;
    }
};

var example = document.getElementById("example").innerHTML;
example=IntSum(arrInt);


<div id="example"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7b8rqme5/

Comment: Wouldn't a for loop be easier for this? And how come you are returning nothing?

Comment: `arr` (l. 14) is not defined...

Comment: Where exactly do you sum up the values?

Answer (score 7):

At no point do you call `CreateArray`.  You call your other function, `IntSum`, which does precisely nothing.  Also, you create a variable `example` and assign a dom element to it, then you immediately overwrite it with a (noop) function result.  There are additional issues with your code as well.

My advice: slow down, determine what it is you need to accomplish, and take it step by step.

Comment: And let's also talk about unconditional `return` in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you wanted. But not really sure what you are trying to do here.

```
var begin = 500000;
var stop = 999999;
var arrInt = [];

var CreateArray = function (begin,stop) {
    while(begin < stop +1){ 
        arrInt.push(begin++);
    }
};

var IntSum = function (ManyInts) {
    var sum = 0 
    var i = ManyInts.length; while (i--) { 
        sum += ManyInts[i];

    }
    return sum;
};

var example = document.getElementById("example").innerHTML;
CreateArray(begin, stop);
var saic=IntSum(arrInt);
document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = saic
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wpnkL6k2/